# How to enable logging DEBUG-level only for the Application Controllers'?

Tags: scala, playframework, logback, play-framework-2.7

I'm on Scala 2.12.x Play 2.7.x and as part of my Application Controllers I'm using the logger like this (or equivalently by doing `with play.api.Logging`):

```
val logger = play.api.Logger(this.getClass)
```

and the configuration `conf/logback.xml` is shown below. The issue is that Application-Controllers' `logger.debug(...)` statements are not being output in the logs. I assumed that the `application` was set to `DEBUG` see one of the lasts entries `<logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />` but there is obviously something wrong as the DEBUG statements are not being output?

```
<!-- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsLogger -->
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="slick" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

PS: I know I can enable DEBUG for everything but then it is too much information I don't need, I'd like to see what's happening with my Controllers' logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger instantiated with `play.api.Logger(this.getClass)` inside a class like so

```
package controller

class HomeController extends ... {
  val logger = play.api.Logger(this.getClass)
  logger.debug("msg")  
}
```

is not the `application` logger, but a distinct logger named

```
controller.HomeController
```

Thus to specify its log level add the following config to `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="controllers" level="DEBUG" />
```

This makes `DEBUG` the log level of all classes under `controllers` package.

Note `application` logger seems to be deprecated according to [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaLogging#Creating-loggers):

> There is also a play.api.Logger singleton object that allows you to
>   access a logger named application, but its use is deprecated in Play
>   2.7.0 and above. You should declare your own logger instances...

If the messages are still not logging try changing from async appender to synchronous ones like so:

```
<root level="WARN">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you yes I knew that, the OP was more about how to enable the Application to DEBUG without getting logging from everywhere else. I will update the Question to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: Wow great! will test it :) what's this entry `<logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />` for then? I assumed everything under `app` .. I tried that too and didn't work `<logger name="app" level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: `application` logger is deprecated but not yet removed, so we can still get access to it like so: `val logger = Logger("application")`

Comment: Ahhhhhh missed that migration entry :D